# How to wrap the MSCRM REST API to graphQL

Tags: dynamics-crm

I just wanted to implement "graphql"  as to wrap it to the REST API of Dynamics dynamics customer relationship management. I just need a basic overview on how it need to be implemented and a working example in the Microsoft customer relationship management  online environment if possible